# C# generics for DbSet<something>

Tags: c#, generics

I have various methods that should be able to call a generic method passing DbSet as a parameter. For the moment I have this working code (shown here simplified):

```
public class MyClass
{
  private async Task<JsonResult> Delete<T>(int? id, T dbs) where T : DbSet<A>
  {
      var row = await dbs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
      dbs.Remove(row);
      await db.SaveChangesAsync();
      return Json(r); // definition od "r" removed from code to simplify it
  }

  public async Task<JsonResult> A(int? id)
  {
      return await Delete(id, db.A);
  }

  public async Task<JsonResult> B(int? id)
  {
      return await Delete(id, db.B);
  }

  public async Task<JsonResult> C(int? id)
  {
      return await Delete(id, db.C);
  }
```

I don't know hot to modify the "Delete" method's signature so that methods A,B,C... can all call it.

Comment: Not sure you want to pass a `DbSet`, maybe it's simpler to call the `context.Set<T>` method?

Comment: Not related to your question, but what is the `Delete` methods supposed to exactly do? It seems that removes an item from the `DbSet<T>` received as argument, then save changes to a totally unrelated context.

Comment: It deletes the element from DbSet corresponding to the received "id".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you reference ID field in your Delete, you need to introduce some interface, like

```
interface IHasID {
    int ID { get; }
}
```

Then you need to implement that interface (in partial class) for all entities with ID. Then you can change your Delete like this

```
private async Task<JsonResult> Delete<T>(int? id, DbSet<T> dbs) where T : class, IHasID {            
    var row = await dbs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
    dbs.Remove(row);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Json(r); // definition od "r" removed from code to simplify it
}
```

And use like this (assuming A implements IHasID):

```
public async Task<JsonResult> A(int? id) {
   return await Delete(id, db.As);
}
```

If you don't want to implement `IHasID` for every entity (though it's very easy, since ID property is already there at your entities), it's possible to do without interface (though less safe because you will be able to pass any entity to this Delete method and you won't find the error until run time):

```
private async Task<JsonResult> Delete<T>(int? id, DbSet<T> dbs) where T : class
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "entity");
    // generate expression entity => entity.ID = id
    var condition = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>) Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(parameter, "ID"),
                Expression.Constant(id)
            )
        , parameter);

    var row = await dbs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(condition);
    dbs.Remove(row);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Json(r);
}
```

Comment: I managed to arrive myself up to `private async Task<JsonResult> Delete<T>(int? id, DbSet<T> dbs) where T : class` and got stuck with the `ID` problem. So I applied your suggestions, created an interface and added it to the class `A`, then to the generic method signature. But the copiler still complains with: The type 'A' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Delete<T>(int?, DbSet<T>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'A' to 'IHasID'.

Comment: You may better post your code completely. Code from my answer I tested and verified it works as expected. Though error suggests that type A still does not implement IHasID.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake of copyng the interface code in two namespaces without realizing it. I confirm that your code works well. **Thank you!**

Comment: You can simplify this even more by removing the `DbSet<T>` parameter. The method signature would be `private async Task<JsonResult> Delete<T>(int? id) where T : class`.

Then the first line would be:

`var dbs = db.Set<T>();`

and to call it, `return await Delete<A>(id);`. This simplification applies regardless of which suggestion you implement.